# common lisp iterate generalized drivers

Tags: loops, common-lisp

I'm going throught the [iterate manual](https://common-lisp.net/project/iterate/doc/) and in section 2.1.3, appears genearlized drivers and in section 2.1.5 previous values of driver variables.

With this thing I want to get the first fiboonacci number bigger that 1000

so I step into this:

```
CL-USER> (iter (initially (setf an-1 1))
               (for an-2 previous an-1 initially 1) 
               (for an-1 next (if (> an-1 1000) (terminate) (+ an-1 an-2)))
               (collect an-1)
               (format t "~a -- ~a~%" an-2 an-1))
```

with the following result:

```
1 -- 2
2 -- 4
4 -- 8
8 -- 16
16 -- 32
32 -- 64
64 -- 128
128 -- 256
256 -- 512
512 -- 1024
(2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024)
```

I do not get how variables inside the loop are growing

Comment: `AN-2` is set to the previous value of `AN-1` before the new value is generated. So when `(+ an-1 an-2)` is evaluated, both variables have the same value. Try using `(for an-2 previous an-1 back 2 initially 1)` instead.

Comment: thanks it worked, but this is not suppoded how thiw should work or no?